# Best translation for "silly"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, adjetivos, insultos

I love the word "silly" in English:

> You're being silly.

It incorporates a sense of humor, playfulness. Google translates it into Spanish as *tonto*, which is just wrong (and almost cost me a relationship; thanks Google).

Is there any good translation for "silly"?

Comment: It is not usually the case, but Google Translate is right. Silly=tonto however depending on the tone you say it you will get the expected result or a fist in your nose. :-)

Answer (score 4):

While *tonto* has more negative nuances than silly, and can easily offend someone, in Argentinian Spanish, the word

> boludo

translates *silly* almost to perfection

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. El equivalente chileno es _pelotudo_, aunque no es tan "suave" entre nosotros como _boludo_ entre los argentinos, alguien podría ofenderse. _Agüevonado_ ya es generalmente ofensivo.

Comment: Pelotudo in Argentina is a pretty strong insult; extremely strong if directed to a woman.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that `silly` may have a wide array of connotations that make difficult to translate the word properly.

I would avoid using "estúpido" and would stick to "tonto", "bobo" o "absurdo".  If I'm trying to make my three year-old laugh my wife might ask him "Is papa being silly?"

> ¿Ya está papá haciendo el **tonto**?
>
> ¿Ya está papá haciendo el **bobo**?

If at work someone points out something is a "silly idea" it would be "absurda" o "tonta". Again, you want to shy away form other words that have stronger connotations like "idiots" or "stupid".

Comment: "bobo" yo lo veo más inocente que "tonto". le pega mas a "silly" ^^

Comment: @lois6b I guess there are regional differences. For me "tonto" is more "light" while _bobo_ is more rude and may cause a bad reaction from the _silly person_

Comment: @DGaleano of course, every region has its own meaning . its dificult but also interesting ^^

Answer (score 3):

I think that *tonto* is the perfect translation for *silly*. It all depends on the way it is pronounced (I have already had lots of conversations about this word with speakers of other languages).

Think about these situations:

- A person comes to you with an angry face and says to you in a harsh way:

  > ¿Pero tú estás tonto?
- Your girlfriend comes to you with a smiling face and says in a playful way:

  > ¡Anda ya, tonto!

Both situations are completely different, the way the word is uttered is completely different, but the word is the same and has completely different meanings and connotations.

Nonetheless, I understand that it may be a dangerous word if you do not know how to use it. If you want to make sure that you use the word in a playful way, use a diminutive variant. I have heard the word used this way a lot in episodes of *Paw Patrol* (*La Patrulla Canina* in Spain, and yes, I also have a small kid):

> ¡Anda ya, tontito!
>   ¡Pero no me seas tontito!

Comment: I think the English word is also subject to the same problems as you outline. If you call the wrong person silly at the wrong time you may have problems. Indeed it would be a silly thing to do.

Comment: I think that _tonto_ has a way stronger nuance to it. Tonto is almost always offensive

Answer (score 0):

This is a little limited, as almost all of my experience comes from Chile. My top choice for silly as you describe it is divertido/a. It isn't so great for speaking about goofiness, but it does speak to sense of humor or playfulness when used to describe a person. Thinking back on people I've known who are that way, this was the word most often used to describe them.

Says the *Diccionario de la Lengua Española* from the Real Academia Española (http://dle.rae.es/?id=E0pO7wd):

> divertido, da
> Del part. de divertir.
>
> 1. adj. Que divierte.
> 2. adj. Alegre, festivo y de buen humor.
> 3. adj. Arg. y Perú. Ligeramente ebrio.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I do not think that has quite the right ring as _silly_ definitely includes doing something slightly wrong but not serious whereas _divertido_ has a more positive sound.

Comment: Nope _silly_ does not translate to _divertido_. _Divertido_ can be translated  as _funny_ or rarely as _enjoyable_, but never as _silly_